# ASP.NET - How To Return Both A Web Response And A View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, razor, blazor

I've got a `servers` controller with an action along the lines of ...

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public class ServersController : Controller
{
    public ServersController(IMemoryCache memoryCache) => Cache = memoryCache;

    private IMemoryCache Cache { get; }

    [HttpGet(Name = "Get Servers")]
    public IActionResult GetServers()
        => Ok(Cache.Get<List<ServerGetDTO>>(Context.ServerList));
}
```

... and I've also got a razor page along the lines of ...

```
@page "/servers"

<PageTitle>Get Servers</PageTitle>

<h1>Gets The Servers (Only Via Response, For Now)</h1>
```

I'm adding the razor/blazor stuff ...

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapRazorPages());
app.MapBlazorHub();
```

... but when I navigate to `https://.../servers` I'm not getting the JSON response that I'm expecting. The expectation is that navigating to the page issues a `Get` request to the endpoint and then I would both get the view to render on the front-end and also the list of servers as JSON as the response for the `Get` call.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE #1: After having added Blazor on top of my API, I've noticed now that Swagger returns HTML when calling the `https://.../servers` endpoint, so the HTML document and the JSON response seem to be mutually-exclussive. I'm almost sure I'm missing something, I'll keep investigating.

UPDATE #2: OK, I've figured it out. Now that I know what the problem was, this question, in hindsight, feels silly. This is my first Blazor experiment, and now I know that I've started with a misunderstanding of the technology at an architectural level. Basically, I've bolted onto my already existing API a Blazor Server project, whereas, in fact I should have used a Blazor WASM project instead. Now that I've replaced Blazor Server with Blazor WASM, everything works exactly as expected!

Comment: Could you please share your full controller class?

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron, I've added the controller definition minus the other actions defined under it and the namespace declaration, which don't feel relevant, but please let me know if it is enough information. Many thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bolt on a front-end to an already existing API, make sure you're adding Blazor WASM, not Blazor Server.